# Simple jQuery .ajax not working on Samsung Galaxy S3

Tags: android, jquery, ajax

I have searched around a lot for this or similar issues and come across a few solutions, but unfortunately they haven't helped.  My issue is I have a simple HTML webpage with a form.  When clicking enter (this is a link not a submit button for the form) it gathers all the data entered into the form and posts it to the client's generic form handler (this processes the data and then stores it into their database).  The page currently works on an iPhone 4 and Samsung Galaxy S2 - but on an S3 the .ajax call will just not run.  Here's my code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "CLIENT_URL", // this is replace with the actual URL in my code and I know works
    data: queryParams,
    cache: false
    success: function(data){

        $('#comp-inner').hide();

        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");

        $('#comp-inner-thanks').show();

    }       
});
```

Like I said this works perfectly fine on other devices...just not the Samsung Galaxy S3 device - can anyone help?  Things I've found and tried:

- used .post instead
- applied cache: false to the ajax options
- tried using jQuery mobile

If anyone can help out that would be awesome, I can imagine it being something silly that I am missing :(

Cheers

Comment: 2 things - have you tried different browsers on the S3 (stock and Chrome, for example), and what actually happens?  Does the success function never fire, or does it fire but not do anything?

Comment: add an error handling function, and see if it goes to that.  
are you sure it's the ajax function that is broken and not whatever is calling it?